# Android: recycler view over tab bar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I need to create an effect similar to starbucks where a listview (or fragment) scrolls over a tab bar.
[image]

I have created a tab bar and below that I have a viewpager with recycler view in it. I am able to move the recyclerview along with tab bar but not able to create effect where my recycler view (which is hosted in viewpager) scrolls over the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

put a scrollListener on your list and in the scrolling put a little animation to the body you are trying to make it scroll over the bar

```
 listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                                     int totalItemCount) { movingBody.setTranslationY(getScroll());}}

protected int getScroll() {// as list recycles views , getscrollY wont give us how much it has scrolled, hence we use this hack
    View firstChildInList = listView.getChildAt(0);
    if (firstChildInList == null) return 0;
    return firstChildInList.getTop() + listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * firstChildInList.getHeight();
}
```

Get scroll is used to determine how much you have scrolled to stop the translation animation
you can make your own condition for the animation to start and to stop instead of getScroll